# When one column of the dataframe is false, how can I assign True to the other column faster?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

As in the title, when the `flag` column is `False`, assign `True` to the `flag2` column.

Is there an `easier way` in the follow line below?

```
df['flag2'] = df.flag == False
```

My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

n1 = range(10)

df = pd.DataFrame(n1, columns=['data'])
df['flag'] = df.data > 5
df['flag2'] = df.flag == False
```

Answer (score 1):

Use inverting by `~`:

```
df['flag2'] = ~df.flag
```